# Can you stack slow movement abilities?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have a wizard and I want use him to kite around the enemies. I am wondering whether the slowing 60% snare from blizzard with rune will stack with the 30% snare from Temporal Flux, if I hit the target with a magic missile.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've tried stacking the Ground stop slow + the Blizzard rune and can confirm that at least those two stack.